# Proof of symmetric bilinear form and orthogonal basis

Tags: linear-algebra

How can I show that the function [image]

[image]

[image]

is a non degenerate symmetric bilinear form and how can I find an orthogonal basis of M2(K) regarding β for char(K)≠2.

Any help would really be appreciated

Comment: It looks like the kind of exercise where you just patiently make all the calcs.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Write the $2\times 2$ matrices as $K^4$ column vectors.

For example, if

$$
M =         \begin{pmatrix}
        x_1 & x_2 \\
        x_3 & x_4 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$

write it as:
$$
        \begin{pmatrix}
        x_1 \\
        x_2 \\
        x_3 \\
        x_4 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$

In that case the bilinear form $f(M) = det(M)$ can be written in terms of components:

$$
f(M) = f(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4) = x_1x_4 - x_2x_3
$$

And the rest is the straight forward procedure of finding the [Hessian Matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hessian_matrix).